# Share data(variables) between lua callback functions in C++

Tags: c++, lua

how I can share/access some data inside several lua callback functions in C++? I know that I can use global c++ variables or some singleton but I don't want to use that.

Hypotetic sample:

```
static int SetParam(lua_State *state) {
  // be able to access nTotalSetParamCalls to do this:
  ++nTotalSetParamCalls;
}

long nTotalSetParamCalls = 0L; // don't want to be it global, I would like to set it to m_luaState and then access it inside callback function
lua_register(m_luaState, "SetParam", SetParam);
luaL_dostring(m_luaState, script);

std::cout << "SetParam was called: " << nTotalSetParamCalls << " times";
```

Thanx in advance

Comment: You could make the callback functions closures (`lua_pushcclosure`) with the data inside the upvalues. To share the upvalues, you would need to unify them with `lua_upvaluejoin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to save your pointer in the lua state:

```
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, new BigObject{});
lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "unique-name");
```

You need to choose this `unique-name` yourself, see the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#4.3) for detail.

Use the corresponding method to obtain this pointer:

```
lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "unique-name");
auto bigObject = (BigObject*)lua_touserdata(L, -1);
lua_pop(L, 1);
```

Comment: Thanx for reply although I don't think this is what I need. Maybe my sample was a little bit tricky. Actually I would like to pass some pointer to much bigger object I could access inside different callback functions and make some actions for it.

Comment: You'd better update your question, add this description and check my update.